# jboss seam + quartz scheduler 2.2.1 + clustering

Tags: quartz-scheduler, load-balancing, seam

I have problem with configuration quartz version 2.2.1 with seam framevork.
Now a get error in log:

> `[24.4.14 12:51:37:843 SELČ] 0000000b SystemOut     O ERROR  manage:3853 - ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failure updating scheduler state when checking-in: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("JDC"."QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE"."SCHED_NAME")`
>
> `org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failure updating scheduler state when checking-in: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
>   ("JDC"."QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE"."SCHED_NAME")
>        [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot
>   insert NULL into ("JDC"."QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE"."SCHED_NAME")
>       ]`
>
> ```
>   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.clusterCheckIn(JobStoreSupport.java:3373)
>   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3226)
>   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3847)
>   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.initialize(JobStoreSupport.java:3832)
>   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:639)
>   at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:513)
>   at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:143)
>   at org.jboss.seam.async.QuartzDispatcher.initScheduler(QuartzDispatcher.java:70)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>   at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
>   at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
>   at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2275)
>   at org.jboss.seam.Component.callCreateMethod(Component.java:2198)
>   at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2158)
>   at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:304)
>   at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:278)
>   at org.jboss.seam.contexts.ServletLifecycle.endInitialization(ServletLifecycle.java:143)
>   at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:744)
>   at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1682)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1163)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:769)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2160)
>   at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5468)
>   at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5594)
>   at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2165)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:995)
>   at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:496)
>   at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1700)
> Caused by: 
> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("JDC"."QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE"."SCHED_NAME")
>
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:85)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:953)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3468)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
>   at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1185)
>   at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:802)
>   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.insertSchedulerState(StdJDBCDelegate.java:3227)
>   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.clusterCheckIn(JobStoreSupport.java:3368)
>   ... 46 more
> ```

My configuration quartz is:

```
#==============================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#==============================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = Sched1
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true

org.quartz.scheduler.userTransactionURL = jta/usertransaction
#==============================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#==============================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

#==============================================================
# Configure JobStore
#==============================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartzDS
#org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource = quartzDSNoTx
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_ 

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 15000
#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.jndiURL= jdc
#org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDSNoTx.jndiURL= java:/jdcNoTX
#org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin 
#org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = jobSchedule.xml
```

Comment: `cannot insert NULL into ("JDC"."QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE"."SCHED_NAME")` seems pretty darn clear.  Stop trying to stick a `NULL` there.  Either you're not passing in the name by accident or the passing is going wrong, or you aren't passing the name *on purpose* and the column isn't set to nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Show your QuartzJobs config file and tell when en error occurs? While compile or when the job should execute?